# Changing the face and moods in python turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x

The user supposed to be prompted to change the face with the following menu:

```
Change My Face
1) Make me frown
2) Make me angry
3) Make my eyes blue
0) Quit
```

If the user selects 1, the smiley face is redrawn with the frown turned to a smile and the menu will change to:

```
Change My Face
1) Make me smile
2) Make me angry
3) Make my eyes blue
0) Quit
```

If the user selects 2, the smiley face is redrawn and filled in red with a frown and the menu will change to:

```
Change My Face
1) Make me smile
2) Make me happy
3) Make my eyes blue
0) Quit
```

We were given starter code to work on this project (with  everywhere we are to add a single line/partial line of code). We also need to and can add methods and data as necessary to this existing code. I am having a hard time understanding class and objects, and this is proving to be a more difficult assignment for me than I originally thought it would be. Here is the starter code we were given (we are defining class in the same file as our main function for convenience):

```py
import turtle

class Face:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__smile = True
        self.__happy = True
        self.__dark_eyes = True

    def draw_face(self):
        turtle.clear()
        self.__draw_head()
        self.__draw_eyes()
        self.__draw_mouth()

    def is_smile(self):
        ___<Fill-In>___

    def is_happy(self):
        ___<Fill-In>___

    def is_dark_eyes(self):
        ___<Fill-In>___

    def change_mouth(self):
        ___<Fill-In>___
        self.draw_face()

    def change_emotion(self):
        ___<Fill-In>___
        self.draw_face()

    def change_eyes(self):
        ___<Fill-In>___
        self.draw_face()


def main():

    face = ___<Fill-In>___
    face.___<Fill-In>___

    done = False

    while not done:
        print("Change My Face")
        mouth = "frown" ____<Fill-In>___ "smile"
        emotion = "angry" ____<Fill-In>___ "happy"
        eyes = "blue" ____<Fill-In>___ "black"
        print("1) Make me", mouth)
        print("2) Make me", emotion)
        print("3) Make my eyes", eyes)
        print("0) Quit")

        menu = eval(input("Enter a selection: "))

        if menu == 1:
            ___<Fill-In>___
        elif menu == 2:
            ___<Fill-In>___
        elif menu == 3:
            ___<Fill-In>___
        else:
            break

    print("Thanks for Playing")

    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.done()


main()
```

I am guessing that should use if else for the fill ins, but other than that I am not sure what any other fill in would be.

```
while not done:
    print("Change My Face")
    mouth = "frown" ____<Fill-In>___ "smile"
    emotion = "angry" ____<Fill-In>___ "happy"
    eyes = "blue" ____<Fill-In>___ "black"
    print("1) Make me", mouth)
    print("2) Make me", emotion)
    print("3) Make my eyes", eyes)
    print("0) Quit")
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's off topic but I'd be dubious of *any* Python 3 instructor or book that gives you starter code like `menu = eval(input("Enter a selection: "))`.  There's no excuse for an `eval()`, vs. an `int()`, here.  Back on topic, you really need to provide the code you've added so far, and tell us why it's not working, otherwise you're just posting your homework assignment for other folks to work on..

Comment: Hello! I am looking for ideas as to what he is looking for in the fill in area. That is the area where I am stuck. I think I could get it after that. Would that be where you draw your face and such?

Answer (score 0):

From top to bottom:

```
def is_smile(self):
        ___<Fill-In>___
```

In python methods that start with 'is' should return a boolean value after some evaluation.
I would guess your instructor wants you to return true if the face .smile attribute is true and false if its false.

```
def change_mouth(self):
        ___<Fill-In>___
        self.draw_face()
```

This function seems like it wants you to change the mouth of the turtle. since it does not accept a value to change to, its safe to assume he wants you to change the value of smile from its current value to the logical alternative. since smile is a boolean, then change it from true to false or false to true.

```
def main():

    face = ___<Fill-In>___
    face.___<Fill-In>___
```

Ok were in the main application now, in order to have a face to play with you need to instantiate a new object of the Face class. 
And then since the init method of the Face class does not do anything to draw the face on the screen it appears he wants you to call the method that draws the face.

```
while not done:
    print("Change My Face")
    mouth = "frown" ____<Fill-In>___ "smile"
    emotion = "angry" ____<Fill-In>___ "happy"
    eyes = "blue" ____<Fill-In>___ "black"
    print("1) Make me", mouth)
    print("2) Make me", emotion)
    print("3) Make my eyes", eyes)
    print("0) Quit")
```

an if else should work great for these. try calling those is_xxx functions you made above.

```
if menu == 1:
            ___<Fill-In>___
        elif menu == 2:
            ___<Fill-In>___
        elif menu == 3:
            ___<Fill-In>___
        else:
            break
```

You need to call the change methods you made above.